# Bash: Run an executable giving a good exit status

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run an executable in Linux, and regardless of the exit status that it returns, I want to return a good exit status. (i.e. no error.)

(This is because I'm using `sh -ex` and I want the script to keep running even if one (specific) command fails.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
command || true
```

From `man bash`:

> The shell does not
>   exit  if  the  command that fails is part of the command
>   list immediately following a  while  or  until  keyword,
>   part  of  the  test  following  the  if or elif reserved
>   words, part of any command executed in a && or  ⎪⎪  list
>   except  the  command  following  the final && or ⎪⎪, any
>   command in a pipeline but the last, or if the  command's
>   return  value  is being inverted with !.

Comment: also a good one :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `(executable ; exit 0)`, or alternatively wrap it in a shell script that always exits 0.

Comment: This works fine for most cases, but it sets up a subshell so if, for example, `(cd foo; exit 0)` is successful, you won't end up in "foo" afterwards since your cwd is returned to the one you were in previously. However, `cd foo || true` will leave you in "foo" if it's successful.

Comment: good point -- if your process has additional side effects (setting environment variables, changing directories, etc.) this won't work out.